# Getting the name of a webserver connected on my LAN

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I want to create a script that finds and locates if a webserver is up an running somewhere inside the local network. My idea was this (not the quickest one). Check all ip's connected to your local network and try to connect to the port that the webserver is listening (let's say it will alwasy listen on 8000). If you find it stop and return the ip. That's the basic idea. I have written my code but not tested it fully yet because my environment has only one Pc at the moment :)....I did run the webserver on my pc though and it id find it. :)

the code looks like that

```
local_host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
web_client_socket = socket.socket()
try:

    if web_client_socket.connect_ex((local_host_ip,8000)) == 0:
        print 'Found rhombus server'
        web_client_socket.close()
        return local_host_ip
except IOError:
    pass

for ip in [ip_address for ip_address in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if 
           ip_address != local_host_ip]:
    print 'Attempting to find server'
    try:

        if web_client_socket.connect_ex((local_host_ip,8000)) == 0:
            print 'Found rhombus server'
            return ip
    except IOError:
        pass
return 'Rhombus server not found'
```

I have tried a similar code where but checking if the webserver is listenning in port 8000 (to see if my idea is working) and it did. What i would like to know at first is if there is a quicker and better way, and second, can I get the name of the webserver? I was thinking that even if this code works what happnes if two web servers (different machines each) were running in 8000?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know beforehand the ip addresses of the hosts in the network (say, have access to the router), I don't think that there is a quickest way than trying each possible ip.

To get the server name  you can do a http request for the index, and retrieve the "Server" http header on the response.

Comment: ty @vinaut. I will try it and then i will make you green(that is accept your answer) :)